# SQLite - joining using Guid return empty

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following `SQLite` query (using `C#`):

```
 command.CommandText = @"SELECT
                                        sd.productuid,
                                        sp.productuid,
                                        sp.description as productname
                                        FROM sale_detail sd
                                        JOIN setup_product sp ON 1  = 1";
```

In this query I get all both tables to see exactly the values of my `productuid` column.

If you see the result you can verify that the `productuid` in one table exists in the other:

[image]

Now, I do the right join:

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT
                                        sd.productuid,
                                        sp.productuid,
                                        sp.description as productname
                                        FROM sale_detail sd
                                        JOIN setup_product sp ON sp.productuid = sd.productuid";
```

[image]

And is empty. This is breaking my head, I don't know why the join is not working even when the `productuid` in table `sale_detail` exists in `setup_product`.

Both fields are `uniqueidentifier`.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Have you checked if you have any hidden characters?  You might try temporarily wrapping the join command with trim().  i.e. trim(sp.productuid) = trim(sd.productuid) and see if that gets a result.

Comment: The values must be different. Try displaying `length(productuid)` and `typeof(productuid)`.